# .NET Core 2.0 xUnit tests not discovered in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, xunit

Im trying to set up VSTS Continuous Integration with a .NET Core 2.0 project and xUnit.

I've got the xunit.runner.visualstudio NuGet package installed, and everything works fine in Visual Studio.

VSTS cant find any tests to run though.

What I could find so far is [this article](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/08/unit-test-with-net-core-and-vsts/), which describes how to set it up with .NET Core 1.0, by using project.json. Unfortunately that wont work, because project.json is gone in .NET Core 2.0.

Any suggestions?

VSTS output:

> 2017-11-08T20:00:30.4824989Z ##[section]Starting: VsTest -
>   testAssemblies 2017-11-08T20:00:30.4834988Z
>   ============================================================================== 2017-11-08T20:00:30.4834988Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
>   2017-11-08T20:00:30.4834988Z Description  : Run tests with Visual
>   Studio test runner 2017-11-08T20:00:30.4834988Z Version      : 2.2.3
>   2017-11-08T20:00:30.4834988Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2017-11-08T20:00:30.4834988Z Help         : [More
>   Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
>   2017-11-08T20:00:30.4834988Z
>   ============================================================================== 2017-11-08T20:00:31.2064989Z Run the tests locally using
>   vstest.console.exe 2017-11-08T20:00:31.2064989Z
>   ======================================================== 2017-11-08T20:00:31.2074983Z Test selector : Test assemblies
>   2017-11-08T20:00:31.2084986Z Test assemblies :
>   **\release*test*.dll,**\release\netcoreapp2.0*Unit*.dll,-:**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll,!**\obj**
>   2017-11-08T20:00:31.2084986Z Test filter criteria : null
>   2017-11-08T20:00:31.2094992Z Search folder : d:\a\1\s
>   2017-11-08T20:00:31.2094992Z Run settings file : d:\a\1\s
>   2017-11-08T20:00:31.2094992Z Run in parallel : false
>   2017-11-08T20:00:31.2115263Z Run in isolation : false
>   2017-11-08T20:00:31.2184982Z Path to custom adapters : null
>   2017-11-08T20:00:31.2194992Z Other console options : null
>   2017-11-08T20:00:31.2194992Z Code coverage enabled : false
>   2017-11-08T20:00:31.2205509Z VisualStudio version selected for test
>   execution : latest 2017-11-08T20:00:32.3430734Z
>   ======================================================== 2017-11-08T20:00:38.4660600Z [command]"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"
>   @d:\a_temp\7a0ab851-c4bf-11e7-9264-0bc93cd5677b.txt
>   2017-11-08T20:00:38.6420650Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line
>   Tool Version 15.0.26929.2 2017-11-08T20:00:38.6420650Z Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   2017-11-08T20:00:38.6420650Z  2017-11-08T20:00:38.6420650Z
>   vstest.console.exe  2017-11-08T20:00:38.6430604Z
>   "d:\a\1\s\Salgsapp\MyTestProject.Business.Unit\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\MyTestProject.Business.Unit.dll"
>   2017-11-08T20:00:38.6430604Z
>   "d:\a\1\s\Salgsapp\MyTestProject.Business.Unit\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\xunit.runner.reporters.netcoreapp10.dll"
>   2017-11-08T20:00:38.6430604Z
>   "d:\a\1\s\Salgsapp\MyTestProject.Business.Unit\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\xunit.runner.utility.netcoreapp10.dll"
>   2017-11-08T20:00:38.6430604Z
>   "d:\a\1\s\Salgsapp\MyTestProject.Business.Unit\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll"
>   2017-11-08T20:00:38.6430604Z /logger:"trx"
>   2017-11-08T20:00:38.6430604Z /TestAdapterPath:"d:\a\1\s"
>   2017-11-08T20:00:39.2010599Z Starting test execution, please wait...
>   2017-11-08T20:00:39.7672139Z Warning: No test is available in
>   d:\a\1\s\Salgsapp\MyTestProject.Business.Unit\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\MyTestProject.Business.Unit.dll
>   d:\a\1\s\Salgsapp\MyTestProject.Business.Unit\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\xunit.runner.reporters.netcoreapp10.dll
>   d:\a\1\s\Salgsapp\MyTestProject.Business.Unit\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\xunit.runner.utility.netcoreapp10.dll
>   d:\a\1\s\Salgsapp\MyTestProject.Business.Unit\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll.
>   Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform &
>   framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
>   2017-11-08T20:00:39.7682139Z  2017-11-08T20:00:39.7812142Z 
>   2017-11-08T20:00:40.6140742Z Information: Additionally, you can try
>   specifying '/UseVsixExtensions' command if the test discoverer &
>   executor is installed on the machine as vsix extensions and your
>   installation supports vsix extensions. Example: vstest.console.exe
>   myTests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true 2017-11-08T20:00:40.6140742Z 
>   2017-11-08T20:00:43.0551327Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.
>   2017-11-08T20:00:43.0711309Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest -
>   testAssemblies

Project definition:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0-preview-20170628-02" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq">
      <Version>4.7.142</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit">
      <Version>2.3.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio">
      <Version>2.3.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyTestProject.Business\MyTestProject.Business.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Build configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify vstest.console.exe in IED\Extensions\TestPlatform folder and framework options in Visual Studio Test task:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Tried that. Seems like VSTS doesnt support the framework. Recieved: Error: Invalid .Net Framework version:.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0. Supported .Net Framework versions are Framework35, Framework40 and Framework45. https://pastebin.com/17Z2DDa9

Comment: Do you specify vstest.console.exe path?

Comment: Yeah, you can see that from the pastebin

Comment: @Kenci The path should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform`, update your build definition and try again.

Comment: That works. Previously I added vstest.console.exe to the path but it should just be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform